# How can I make my mouse cursor invisible but still working

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-cursor

I am playing a Emulator that does not give me the possibility to make the cursor invisible. Is there a way to do this within windows? Maybe with a batch or a script, or via settings?

I am on a Windows 10 PC

Comment: From a programmers perspective, it is really easy to implement this into your windows program. If it is not possible with that emulator, it would be far easier if they implemented this than you hack something together that does this. For them it can be as easy as one line of code, or setting one setting for one object. Therefor, I would email them and suggest them to add this.

Comment: @LPChip so you are suggesting that for me there is not much i can do? Besides hoping that they fix this to my request?

Comment: I did not say that. There are a few ways to accomplish this, but they are very much hacky and it is far easier, both for you and for them if the program supports it natively. You can create (and possibly download) an empty.cur file and set that as your mouse cursor to hide it. There are also programs that can do this. In either case, once you set the mouse like this, but to do it only temporarily is usually quite hard to do.

Comment: It is also possible to create a cursor yourself using some programs. You could make it a 1 pixel inversed cursor. That way you still see the one pixel, so you can see where the cursor is, but other than that, a program that has its own cursor will show it better.